# gridview display + multiple where clause

Tags: c#, sql

I have a gridview which should display only usernames based on the email written in textbox1 and textbox2. How can I do this? I bound the gridview to a sql data source and in tht, I used the where clause like

```
SELECT [Username] FROM [Users] WHERE (([Email] = @Email) AND ([Email] = @Email2))
```

Where control ID on email is textbox 1 and control ID of email2 is textbox 2. But the result is null. The gridview is not displaying anything.

Comment: Change 'AND' to 'OR', or IN statement, IN(@Email, @Email2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [Username] FROM [Users] WHERE [Email] in (@Email, @Email2)
```

is the correct SELECT statement.

Alternatively, you could do

```
SELECT [Username] FROM [Users] WHERE (([Email] = @Email) OR ([Email] = @Email2))
```

(note the **OR** instead of **AND**)

The problem with your SELECT is that it retrieves the rows that are equal to **both** @Email and @Email2. You could test that by trying to set the same email value in both text boxes - that should bring some results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an OR instead of an AND in the WHERE clause.